# Automatically spilt cell info based on ","

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out a way to split a cell containing multiple URLs automatically based on the spreadsheet opening. I need the cell to split into multiple cells horizontally based on a comma at the end of each URL.

Very new to this all.

Comment: Do you want the information removed and split so the original item no longer exists or can you keep the original information and have the split text appear in cells following the original?

Answer (score 1):

most likely this is what you need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ",")))
```

[image: 0]